# Função 1 chama função 2 porém função 1 encerra antes do return da função 2

Tags: javascript, ajax

tenho 2 funções no JavaScript, a 1º, `mudarForecast()`, é chamada mediante um onchange de um select no HTML, e a 2º, `getTotalEMeta()`, é chamada após um if/else dentro da função 1. A `getTotalEMeta()` eu também uso para outros fins, portanto decidi que para saber que está sendo chamada pela `mudarForecast()` eu passo o 1º parâmetro como `false` e, após o retorno do ajax, escrevi uma condição para que retornasse o valor do response sempre que `ajax1 == false`.

O problema: Na minha visão, o algoritmo está correta, porém sempre que faço depuração o caminho é:

1. Entra na `mudarForecast()`.
2. Desce até o `let resp_getTotalEMeta`.
3. Entra na `getTotalEMeta()` e vai até a linha do `$.ajax()`.
4. Ignora o `$.ajax()`, pula até o final de `getTotalEMeta()`, volta na `mudarForecast()` e continua a partir do `console.log()` (nesse momento vai imprimir `resp_getTotalEMeta` como undefined).
5. Encerra a `mudarForecast()` e volta para `getTotalEMeta()`, aí sim, a partir do `$.ajax()`.
6. Faz certinho o `$.ajax()` e retorna belezinha o `resp_getTotalEMeta`, mas agora retorna para ninguém.
7. Encerra o `if (resp1 == false)` e fim.

Função 1:

```
function mudarForecast(aux, option_value, innerHTML) {
    let dtInicial = document.getElementById("dtInicial").value;
    let produto_escolhido = document.getElementById("produto").value;
    let forecast = document.getElementById("div_forecast");
    let lista = document.getElementById("div_lista_forecast");

    if (aux == true) {
        forecast.style.display = "none";
        lista.style.display = "inline-flex";
    } else { // Essa é a parte que importa nesse caso. *****************
        let cod_prod_programados = [produto_escolhido];
        let novaData = (new Date((new Date(dtInicial+"T00:00")).setMonth(option_value, 1))).toISOString().split('T')[0];
        
        // Aqui começa a parte que o código chama a 2º função. ***********
        let resp_getTotalEMeta = getTotalEMeta(false, "", "", "", "", novaData, "", "", cod_prod_programados, "");

        console.log(resp_getTotalEMeta);
    }
}
```

Função 2:

```
function getTotalEMeta(resp1, resp2, ano, mes, resp3, dtInicial, dtFinal, produto_escolhido, cod_prod_programados, id_semana) {
    let produto = cod_prod_programados;
    
    // Aqui é onde o código para e só volta após a 1ª função ser encerrada. ******
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../controllers/produtoController.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            method: "getAllForecastAjax",
            dtInicial: dtInicial,
            produto: produto
        },
        success: function(response) {
            let resp_getTotalEMeta = JSON.parse(response4);

            if (resp1 == false)
                return resp_getTotalEMeta; // Esse é o return que eu gostaria de receber. *******
            
            else
                getOPsDisponiveis(resp1, resp2, ano, mes, ajax3, resp4, produto_escolhido, cod_prod_programados, id_semana);
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            console.log(request.responseponseText);
        }
    })
}
```

Não consigo ver aonde estou errando. Minha intenção era que o `console.log(resp_getTotalEMeta)` imprimisse certinho o valor de `resp_getTotalEMeta` após o retorno da função `getTotalEMeta()`. Por favor podem me ajudar a encontrar meu erro?

Comment: `getTotalEMeta` é assíncrona, ou seja `mudarForecast` não vai esperar pelo resultado dela para continuar a execução, a opção mais simples seria adicionar a opção `async: false` no seu ajax. Além disso não tem como pegar diretamente o return de `success`, você teria que criar uma outra variável além de produto e atribuir o JSON.parse(response) do ajax nela e retornar essa variável no final do método getTotalEMeta, após a execução do ajax.

Comment: Além do que @Benilson comentou, o `return` do success não serve para `getTotalEMeta`, esse `return` está dentro de uma função anônima que está sendo passada na propriedade `success`, ou seja ele só funciona dentro do escopo daquela função, em outras palavras ele encerra a função atribuída ao `success` e não influencia no fluxo de `getTotalEMeta`

Comment: Funcionou @Benilson, adicionei `async: false` no ajax e declarei uma 2º variável em `getTotalEMeta` para dar return somente no final da função, e agora foi certinho como eu estava querendo. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado também @coheia (o site não me permitiu citar 2 users no mesmo comment).